# Rewrite Rule to change multiple get parameters depending of given get parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, typo3

I need a rewrite rule to change some get parameters, but only if two specific get parameters exists.

The URL is called by a payment provider (VR Payment Click + Pay) as a callback, where it is **not** possible to change there added GET parameters (id + resourcePath).
Unfortunately the parameter `id` is already used by the CMS TYPO3, where I try to implement here crap.

As a workaround of there incompetence, my idea is now to redirect requests like this:
`https://domain.tld/subpageA/subpageB/?id=ABC123&resourcePath=/v1/pathXYZ`

to urls like this using mod_rewrite:
`https://domain.tld/subpageA/subpageB/?vendorId=ABC123&vendorResourcePath=/v1/pathXYZ`

So basically I "only" need to rewrite the GET parameters id -> vendorId and resourcePath -> vendorResourcePath, but only if both (id + resourcePath) are set.

This was my last try (after several hours try and error), but I did **not** get it working :-(

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)&resourcePath=([^&]*)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^|&))id=([^&]*)&?(.*)&?$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^|&))resourcePath=([^&]*)&?(.*)&?$
    RewriteRule "(.*)" "$1?%1&vendorId=%2&vendorResourcePath=%3"
```

Maybe a mod_rewrite crack can help me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile a found a solution, simpler than expected:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)&resourcePath=([^&]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule "(.*)" "$1?vendorId=%1&vendorResourcePath=%2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting rewrite rules right is hard i find this tool helps a lot in understanding what is happening https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Another option woul be to configure the callback url to somthing like `/callback/` and rewrite and redirect every request in /callback/

Or you could use a middleware to process the request and rewrite with the full power of php.

Comment: I already tried to use a middleware, but it didn't worked, because of the htaccess rules, which are handled ealier. My middleware was never reached, independent where I put it in the stack.

Comment: But https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ looks genious!